# JAXB "rename" property from a parent class in a child class

Tags: java, jaxb

If I have parent class A

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class A {
    private int id;
}
```

and a child class B

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class B extends A {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;
}
```

In the system there are also many classes C, D, X, Y, Z which extend class A.

I would like to "rename" the property `A#id` to `B#somethingId` only for instances of B.

My idea was to redeclare field id and to use `XmlTransient` but it is not working, I still have "id" in when marshalling B:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class B extends a {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public Long getSomethingId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setSomethingId(Long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }   

    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setId(Long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

}
```

The output is

```
   <B>
          <id>
          <somethingId>
          ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name= "B")
public class B extends A {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;


    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "somethingId")
    public void setId(int id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class A {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Notice the @XmlAccessorType is set to XmlAccessType.PROPERTY.

Or you could also do it with XmlAccessType.FIELD, like this:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
    @XmlTransient
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name= "B")
public class B extends A {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "somethingId")
    public void setId(int id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

}
```

Edit to reply to the comment:

You can of course keep the id in the classes you want. For example, following the second approach, adding a class like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name= "C")
public class C extends A {
    private int j;
    private int k;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

}
```

would work just fine. If I use a simple main to demo it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class, C.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            B b = new B();
            b.setId(1);
            marshaller.marshal(b, System.out);

            System.out.println();

            C c = new C();
            c.setId(2);
            marshaller.marshal(c, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Would give you the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<B>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <z>0</z>
    <somethingId>1</somethingId>
</B>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<C>
    <j>0</j>
    <k>0</k>
    <id>2</id>
</C>
```

Or is it something you don't like in this approach?

Comment: Thank you for this. I've thought of this, but the issue is that I have 10 or so more subclasses of `A` where I do need the property with the name `id`.

Comment: I will reply in the post, for convenience

Comment: Hey @mart, that works. But the trouble with it is that any developer creating a new subclass of `A` would have to take care and implement `id`. I feel that the default value should be specified in `A`.

What I'm looking for is something along `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties` equivalent in JAXB.

Comment: Hi @RockyMM, yes I got the feeling that you may didn't like the repetition. Tried to find a way to avoid it, but didn't make it yet.